# Aggregating true/false sequences in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in psql with an `id` column, `timestamp` column and `has_connection` column

```
 id |         ts          | has_connection 
----+---------------------+----------------
  1 | 2016-06-22 19:10:25 | t
  1 | 2016-06-22 19:10:26 | t
  1 | 2016-06-22 19:10:27 | f
  1 | 2016-06-22 19:10:28 | t
  1 | 2016-06-22 19:10:29 | f
  1 | 2016-06-22 19:10:30 | f
  1 | 2016-06-22 19:10:31 | t
  1 | 2016-06-22 19:10:32 | t
```

My goal is to get cases when a FALSE or sequence of FALSEs begin, and when they end.

```
SELECT *,  CASE WHEN lag(has_connection) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ts ASC) <>  has_connection  THEN 'change' ELSE 'no_change' END as change FROM test

 id |         ts          | has_connection |  change   
----+---------------------+----------------+-----------
  1 | 2016-06-22 19:10:25 | t              | no_change
  1 | 2016-06-22 19:10:26 | t              | no_change
  1 | 2016-06-22 19:10:27 | f              | change
  1 | 2016-06-22 19:10:28 | t              | change
  1 | 2016-06-22 19:10:29 | f              | change
  1 | 2016-06-22 19:10:30 | f              | no_change
  1 | 2016-06-22 19:10:31 | t              | change
  1 | 2016-06-22 19:10:32 | t              | no_change
```

The above will get me where the flips happen, but what is the most efficient way to produce the output below that I need ?

```
 id |     connection_end  | reconnect
----+---------------------+----------------
  1 | 2016-06-22 19:10:27 | 2016-06-22 19:10:28 
  1 | 2016-06-22 19:10:29 | 2016-06-22 19:10:31
```

here is the data:

```
CREATE TABLE test  (id INT, ts TIMESTAMP, has_connection BOOL);

INSERT INTO test (id, ts, has_connection)
VALUES
   (
      1,
      '2016-06-22 19:10:25',
      TRUE
  ),(
      1,
      '2016-06-22 19:10:26',
      TRUE
  ),(
      1,
      '2016-06-22 19:10:27',
      FALSE
  ),(
      1,
      '2016-06-22 19:10:28',
      TRUE
  ),(
      1,
      '2016-06-22 19:10:29',
      FALSE
  ),(
      1,
      '2016-06-22 19:10:30',
      FALSE
  ),(
      1,
      '2016-06-22 19:10:31',
      TRUE
  ),(
      1,
      '2016-06-22 19:10:32',
      TRUE
   );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to assign a grouping to `false`s with the same group as the following `true`.  This is a variant on the standard gaps-and-islands problem.

You can calculate the grouping do this by counting the number of `true` values *on or after a give row*.  All `false` have the same value.  And the following `true` (if any) does as well.

Then aggregate:

```
select id,
       min(ts) as connection_end, max(ts) as reconnect
from (select t.*,
             count(*) filter (where has_connection) over (order by ts desc) as grp
      from test t
     ) t
group by id, grp
having not (array_agg(has_connection order by ts))[1]
order by min(ts);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=8a020eb15cc02c8338858fdac54db611) is a db<>fiddle.

The filtering on this is a little tricky.  The inner subquery correctly identifies the groups.  However, the groups can have both true and false values, so you cannot simply filter on `has_connection`.  Instead, one method is to check if the first value in each group is `false`.

Another method is just to check if there are *any* `false` values in the group.  These always come before any `true`, so the two are equivalent.  This is phrased as:

```
having bool_or(not has_connection)
```

Also, this assumes that the last value has always true.  If the sequence can end with a `true` value, then this is more accurate:

```
select id, min(ts) as connection_end,
       max(ts) filter (where has_connection) as reconnect
from (select t.*,
             count(*) filter (where has_connection) over (order by ts desc) as grp
      from test t
     ) t
group by id, grp
having not (array_agg(has_connection order by ts))[1]
order by min(ts)
```

Comment: Thank you for this trip - is there a way to write
`count(*) filter (where has_connection) over (order by ts desc) as grp`
differently?  My version of PrestoSQL does not support FILTER for window functions

Or another way to get :
 grp 
-----
   1
   2
   2
   2
   3
   3
   4
   5

Comment: @the_darkside . . . You can also use `count( has_connection::int )`.

Comment: this works, but the `array_agg` method is very slow on 100M + records ... @Gordon Linoff might there be more optimal solution that is faster on a large dataset ?

Comment: @the_darkside . . . I don't know if it will make much difference, but try the `bool_or()`.

Answer (score 1):

With lag() window function:

```
select *,
  case when has_connection = 
    coalesce(lag(has_connection, 1) over (partition by id order by ts), has_connection)
    then 'no_change' else 'change'
  end change  
from test
order by id, ts
```

Results:

```
| id  | ts                       | has_connection | change    |
| --- | ------------------------ | -------------- | --------- |
| 1   | 2016-06-22T19:10:25.000Z | true           | no_change |
| 1   | 2016-06-22T19:10:26.000Z | true           | no_change |
| 1   | 2016-06-22T19:10:27.000Z | false          | change    |
| 1   | 2016-06-22T19:10:28.000Z | true           | change    |
| 1   | 2016-06-22T19:10:29.000Z | false          | change    |
| 1   | 2016-06-22T19:10:30.000Z | false          | no_change |
| 1   | 2016-06-22T19:10:31.000Z | true           | change    |
| 1   | 2016-06-22T19:10:32.000Z | true           | no_change |
```

You can use a similar query as a CTE to get the final results:

```
with 
  changes as (
    select *,
      case when has_connection = 
        coalesce(lag(has_connection, 1) over (partition by id order by ts), has_connection)
        then false else true
      end changed  
    from test
  ), 
  rows as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by id, has_connection order by ts) rn
    from changes
    where changed
  )
select r1.id, r1.ts connection_end, r2.ts reconnect          
from rows r1 inner join rows r2
on r2.id = r1.id and r2.rn = r1.rn
where not r1.has_connection and r2.has_connection
```

Results:

```
id | connection_end      | reconnect          
 1 | 2016-06-22 19:10:27 | 2016-06-22 19:10:28
 1 | 2016-06-22 19:10:29 | 2016-06-22 19:10:31
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=8eb61ab0adf5450dcc66cf4b820c89da).

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using recursive CTE:

```
with recursive cte as (
    (select id, null::timestamp as connection_end, ts as reconnect, has_connection 
     from test order by ts limit 1)
    union all
    (select test.id, cte.reconnect, test.ts, test.has_connection
     from test join cte on (test.ts > cte.reconnect and test.has_connection <> cte.has_connection)
     order by test.ts limit 1))
select * from cte where has_connection and connection_end is not null;
```